# How to set a numeric value in defaultValues for react-hook-form in order to be required?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-hook-form

There is a form that contains two inputs, a string and a number both being required.

Here is the schema:

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required(),
  age: yup.number().required()
});
```

Afterwards, it is react-hook-form:

```
  const { handleSubmit, reset, control, register, watch } = useForm({
    defaultValues: emptyObject,
    resolver: yupResolver(schema)
  });
```

As you can see, there is `defaultValues` which has `emptyObject`.

Here it is:

```
const emptyObject = {
  name: '',
  age: 0
}
```

The `name` part works fine, I cannot submit the data if there is no input written in that textbox but for age it doesn't require any value. I know it checks for value and it finds it is `0` and it considers there is an input.

But how to change it to make it work? Tried with `null` but still doesn't work.

I have to mention that it is React with Typescript so there is also an interface which throws error when age is set to `null`.

```
  MyData: {
    name: string;
    age: number;
  }
```

Comment: can't You remove default values? why do you need one? and you can put a placeholder instead of default value

Answer (score 2):

Make the `age` an empty `string` as well, just for your needs and when its time to submit the form just add some functionality to convert the string to number if its critical for your app.

From the DOCS, you can not set it to any `undefined` value:
***It is encouraged that you set a defaultValue for all inputs to non-undefined such as the empty string or null.***

[Link to DOCS](https://react-hook-form.com/kr/v6/api/)

Comment: regex will help in this situation  -  https://wisetut.com/only-numbers-in-regex-regular-expression/

Comment: This defeats like 95% of the reason for using yup in the first place... A real shame.